# Allocating Memory for an Array of SHA1 Digests

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, malloc

I have a small program that generates an SHA1 digest for arguments passed via command line and stores them in an array of pointers to char arrays (I think):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int entries = 0; // Keep track of entries added

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Allocate space for the digest array
    unsigned char **mds = malloc(1);

    // Add entries to the digest, one for each argument passed  
    for(int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
        mds[k - 1] = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
        SHA1(argv[k], strlen(argv[k]), mds[k - 1]);
        entries++;
    }

    // Print each 20-byte digest
    for(int j = 0; j < entries; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) { printf("%02x ", *(mds[j] + i)); }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Originally I had `unsigned char **mds = calloc(argc, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);` and I was going to try to use `realloc()` everytime I wanted to add another entry (if I didn't know how many entries I was going to have later).

But then I found out that I didn't need to do that and I didn't even need to allocate any space at all? Just a byte and it still works just fine. That doesn't seem right to me.

Am I just lucking out or something? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
// Allocate space for the digest array
unsigned char **mds = malloc(1);
```

allocates a memory block of size `1` byte and casts its address to `unsigned char**`. Then later in the first iteration already, when you do:

```
mds[k - 1] = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

the `malloc` returns an address, which is written into the invalid memory causing *undefined behavior*.

---

You need to allocate appropriate memory block that will hold *pointers* and in every iteration you will initialize each of these pointers to point to the memory block that will hold *string*:

```
// allocate array of pointers:
unsigned char **mds = malloc( (argc - 1) * sizeof(unsigned char*) );

for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
    mds[k - 1] = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    SHA1(argv[k], strlen(argv[k]), mds[k - 1]);
    entries++;
}
...
// cleaning up:
for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
    free(mds[k - 1]);
}
free(mds);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Am I just lucking out or something?

Yes.

> What am I missing?

Your program writes outside of the allocated memory.  Doing so causes undefined behaviour.  Anything could happen, including the appearance of correct behaviour.

Adding some `free()` calls will probably turn up some crashers, but no guarantees - undefined behaviour is undefined, after all.

Comment: So I should keep `unsigned char **mds = calloc(argc, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);` and use `realloc()` in the loop in the event that I don't know `argc`, correct?

Comment: Why not just allocate `argc` entries to begin with?  That `calloc` call seems strange.

Comment: In the event that I don't actually know how many entries I will have, instead of taking CL arguments.

Comment: ... but `argc` *tells* you how many command line arguments you have.

Comment: Yes I know, but if I were to move this code to it's own function inside of another program where the strings to hash aren't actually passed by command line.

Comment: Then you could pass a number to that function.  I don't see how it's a problem.  You have to know how many you're operating on *somewhere*, right?

Answer (score 2):

You are writing in memory not allocated to you. Lucky that you have no crashes so far.

Try using valgrind if it is available on your platform. It will tell you about memory errors both of this variety and when you allocate memory that you forget to free.  The program will run slower but you only need to do it for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Valgrind, I will definitely be using it!